# memory which contains 16 addresses (numbered 0..15), and each location stores a 3-bit binary number

Tags: memory, binary

i just want to do this in **programming in logic** i just tried to make stack but i don't know how i can do this or reserve those addresses of memory ? that's should be a memory system but i can't understand how to reserve those addresses so i can input my binary number in.
this site include my problem
[enter link description here](http://www-id.imag.fr/~briat/perso.html/NACHOS/NACHOS_DOC/CA225b.html)
i tried set stack or even make a stack but seems wrong `set_stack` or `limit`